# How to flash the scrollbar thumb of a scrollable div with "webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch"

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit, scroll, ios5

Is there any way to flash (i.e. make visible for a short moment) the scrollbar thumb of an HTML div where "native scrolling" is enabled, i.e. a div where "overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" styles are set and the content is large enough to overflow?

I'd like to flash the scrollbar thumb on changes of the div's content's size, as users would expect from native apps.

Setting the scroll offsets of the scrollable element doesn't seem to make the scrollbar thumb visible.